# How to fetch as word from a string in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
string = "Status\t\t: PASS"
```

I want to fetch only PASS from this string and I am using this regex.

```
value = re.findall("Status" + r'(.*)', string)
```

But it returns me this

```
"           : PASS"
```

I want the regex to ignore all extra characters spaces tabs etc. Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: basically, you want to return the string after `Status:` right?

Comment: @VikasP yes Vikas I only want PASS

Answer (score 3):

Method : Using regex() + string.punctuation
This method also used regular expressions, but string function of getting all the punctuations is used to ignore all the punctuation marks and get the filtered result string.

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# to extract words from string 
# using regex() + string.punctuation 
import re 
import string 

# initializing string 
test_string = "Geeksforgeeks, is best @# Computer Science Portal.!!!"

# printing original string 
print ("The original string is : " + test_string) 

# using regex() + string.punctuation 
# to extract words from string 
res = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', test_string).split() 

# printing result 
print ("The list of words is : " + str(res))
```

Output:

```
The original string is : Geeksforgeeks, is best @# Computer Science Portal.!!!
The list of words is : [‘Geeksforgeeks’, ‘is’, ‘best’, ‘Computer’, ‘Science’, ‘Portal’]
```

Comment: I want to return the string after Status. I dont want to get all words in a string

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re
string = "Status\t\t: PASS"
m = re.search(r'Status\s*:\s*(.*)', string)
print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
PASS
```

Explanation of the regex `Status\s*:\s*(.*)`:

- `Status\s*` matches substring "Status" and following blank characters as may as possible if any.
- `:\s*` matches a character ":" and following blank characters as many as possible if any.
- `(.*)` matches the remaining substring and capture group 1 is assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrVK7Z/1/)

Python-source:

```
import re

input1 = "Status\t\t: PASS"
input2 = "Status\t\t: PASS hello"
input3 = "Status\t\t: FAIL hello world"
regex=re.compile('status\s*:\s*(\w+)',flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(f'result of input1: \n {regex.findall(input1)}')
print(f'result of input2: \n {regex.findall(input2)}')
print(f'result of input3: \n {regex.findall(input3)}')
```

Out-put:

```
result of input1: 
 ['PASS']
result of input2: 
 ['PASS']
result of input3: 
 ['FAIL']
```